# jQuery div slide transitions don't work properly in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: jquery, slide

I have a problem with general slide animation of one page. I have spent half of a day trying to sort this out and I just gave up. Maybe someone more familiar with jQuery will be able to spot the problem. The problem exists while you are trying to switch between last 2 subpages (divs): gallery and contact... 
Basically the page is made from div's (which are something like subpages) and they slide up and down depending of the user's choice. Here is the actual page: `http://4play.dj/home.html` (sorry, system doesn't allow .dj domain I guess). The page **works really well in IE**, which is weird, as usually the problem is the other way. I have created a fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/tucado/mcCzF/4/), but for some reason it doesn't work for me. Any help will be well appreciated. Thank you very much in advance.

jQuery code below (the code is here: sorry for that much, but the problem may exist everywhere, I went line by line 10000 times and found nothing):

```
    ;(function( $ ){

        var $scrollTo = $.scrollTo = function( target, duration, settings ){
            $(window).scrollTo( target, duration, settings );
        };

        $scrollTo.defaults = {
            axis:'xy',
            duration: parseFloat($.fn.jquery) >= 1.3 ? 0 : 1
        };

        // Returns the element that needs to be animated to scroll the window.
        // Kept for backwards compatibility (specially for localScroll & serialScroll)
        $scrollTo.window = function( scope ){
            return $(window)._scrollable();
        };

        // Hack, hack, hack :)
        // Returns the real elements to scroll (supports window/iframes, documents and regular nodes)
        $.fn._scrollable = function(){
            return this.map(function(){
                var elem = this,
                    isWin = !elem.nodeName || $.inArray( elem.nodeName.toLowerCase(), ['iframe','#document','html','body'] ) != -1;

                    if( !isWin )
                        return elem;

                var doc = (elem.contentWindow || elem).document || elem.ownerDocument || elem;

                return $.browser.safari || doc.compatMode == 'BackCompat' ?
                    doc.body : 
                    doc.documentElement;
            });
        };

        $.fn.scrollTo = function( target, duration, settings ){
            if( typeof duration == 'object' ){
                settings = duration;
                duration = 0;
            }
            if( typeof settings == 'function' )
                settings = { onAfter:settings };

            if( target == 'max' )
                target = 9e9;

            settings = $.extend( {}, $scrollTo.defaults, settings );
            // Speed is still recognized for backwards compatibility
            duration = duration || settings.speed || settings.duration;
            // Make sure the settings are given right
            settings.queue = settings.queue && settings.axis.length > 1;

            if( settings.queue )
                // Let's keep the overall duration
                duration /= 2;
            settings.offset = both( settings.offset );
            settings.over = both( settings.over );

            return this._scrollable().each(function(){
                var elem = this,
                    $elem = $(elem),
                    targ = target, toff, attr = {},
                    win = $elem.is('html,body');

                switch( typeof targ ){
                    // A number will pass the regex
                    case 'number':
                    case 'string':
                        if( /^([+-]=)?\d+(\.\d+)?(px|%)?$/.test(targ) ){
                            targ = both( targ );
                            // We are done
                            break;
                        }
                        // Relative selector, no break!
                        targ = $(targ,this);
                    case 'object':
                        // DOMElement / jQuery
                        if( targ.is || targ.style )
                            // Get the real position of the target 
                            toff = (targ = $(targ)).offset();
                }
                $.each( settings.axis.split(''), function( i, axis ){
                    var Pos = axis == 'x' ? 'Left' : 'Top',
                        pos = Pos.toLowerCase(),
                        key = 'scroll' + Pos,
                        old = elem[key],
                        max = $scrollTo.max(elem, axis);

                    if( toff ){// jQuery / DOMElement
                        attr[key] = toff[pos] + ( win ? 0 : old - $elem.offset()[pos] );

                        // If it's a dom element, reduce the margin
                        if( settings.margin ){
                            attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('margin'+Pos)) || 0;
                            attr[key] -= parseInt(targ.css('border'+Pos+'Width')) || 0;
                        }

                        attr[key] += settings.offset[pos] || 0;

                        if( settings.over[pos] )
                            // Scroll to a fraction of its width/height
                            attr[key] += targ[axis=='x'?'width':'height']() * settings.over[pos];
                    }else{ 
                        var val = targ[pos];
                        // Handle percentage values
                        attr[key] = val.slice && val.slice(-1) == '%' ? 
                            parseFloat(val) / 100 * max
                            : val;
                    }

                    // Number or 'number'
                    if( /^\d+$/.test(attr[key]) )
                        // Check the limits
                        attr[key] = attr[key] <= 0 ? 0 : Math.min( attr[key], max );

                    // Queueing axes
                    if( !i && settings.queue ){
                        // Don't waste time animating, if there's no need.
                        if( old != attr[key] )
                            // Intermediate animation
                            animate( settings.onAfterFirst );
                        // Don't animate this axis again in the next iteration.
                        delete attr[key];
                    }
                });

                animate( settings.onAfter );            

                function animate( callback ){
                    $elem.animate( attr, duration, settings.easing, callback && function(){
                        callback.call(this, target, settings);
                    });
                };

            }).end();
        };

        // Max scrolling position, works on quirks mode
        // It only fails (not too badly) on IE, quirks mode.
        $scrollTo.max = function( elem, axis ){
            var Dim = axis == 'x' ? 'Width' : 'Height',
                scroll = 'scroll'+Dim;

            if( !$(elem).is('html,body') )
                return elem[scroll] - $(elem)[Dim.toLowerCase()]();

            var size = 'client' + Dim,
                html = elem.ownerDocument.documentElement,
                body = elem.ownerDocument.body;

            return Math.max( html[scroll], body[scroll] ) 
                 - Math.min( html[size]  , body[size]   );

        };

        function both( val ){
            return typeof val == 'object' ? val : { top:val, left:val };
        };

    })( jQuery );

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('a.panel').click(function () {

            $('a.panel').removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            current = $(this);

            $('#wrapper').scrollTo($(this).attr('href'), 800);      

            return false;
        });

        $(window).resize(function () {
            resizePanel();
        });

    });

    function resizePanel() {

        width = $(window).width();
        height = $(window).height();

        mask_height = height * $('.item').length;

        $('#debug').html(width  + ' ' + height + ' ' + mask_height);

        $('#wrapper, .item').css({width: width, height: height});
        $('#mask').css({width: width, height: mask_height});
        $('#wrapper').scrollTo($('a.selected').attr('href'), 0);

    }
```

HTML > http://4play.dj/home.html
CSS > http://4play.dj/_css/home.css

Thanks again

Comment: did you try to switch between the last 2 options? so gallery and contact?

Comment: I though they not implemented, fun thing, when i start debugger it work fine...

Comment: you tried to rewrite scrollTo ? what is incorrect with scrollTo plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 window.onload = function () {
 resizePanel()
 }
```

hopefully that will work since the functionality is working when you actually resize the page

Comment: getting rid of height all together on the css item actually fixed it for me on FF

Comment: funny when working on it in chrome it doesn't work on initial load but when you resize the window - it works - call the function you are doing on resize and apply to window.onload = function () {}

Comment: I realized when I'm working in firebug you actually are re-sizing the window so I attributed that to my css but actually is the function you are calling on resize that makes it work correctly in FF and chrome